# Getting type-error using custom middleware in specific view

Tags: django, django-middleware

This is my middleware

```
class HasAccessMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        print("init")
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        allowed_ips = WebSettings.get_allowed_ip()
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')  # Get client IP
        if ip not in allowed_ips:
            return HttpResponse("false", status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        print("call")
        return self.get_response(request)
```

this is my setting

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'tools.middleware.HasAccessMiddleware',
```

)

and this is my view

```
@decorator_from_middleware(HasAccessMiddleware)
def json_backup(request):
    pass
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Would you help me find what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need it as a decorator at all, since you've included it in MIDDLEWARE so it will always be executed anyway?

Comment: I just want it to run on the json_backup view, not anywhere else.

Comment: The docs [state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware): "It assumes middleware that’s compatible with the old style of Django 1.9 and earlier". So this can't work. But if you need it to just run on that one view, why don't you put the functionality into the view itself? The relevant part is just four lines.

Comment: because I have five more views like this one, I just want to write a middleware what run on these six views, not all views I have

Comment: So why not write it as a decorator directly?

Comment: I thought that writing a middleware is the solution to this problem, isn't it? So I have to solve it with a decorator?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want to use this on six views, then write it directly as a decorator.

```
def has_access(view_func):
    @functools.wraps(view_func)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        allowed_ips = WebSettings.get_allowed_ip()
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')  # Get client IP
        if ip not in allowed_ips:
            return HttpResponse("false", status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now you can decorate your views with `@has_access`.